# Using android native method in react native for compass

Tags: android, react-native

I am relatively new to mobile application development and i am creating a direction compass application in react-native. Have tried using most of the libraries that exist but the compass starts fluctuating when device is in rest. I now have 2 options : -

1. Is there any solution using js itself in react-native to solve this fluctuating issue ?
2. I am planning to create a method in native android which will calculate the compass value using devices sensor and then passing that value in react-native application . Is this possible ? If yes then how do i implement it ?

Also feel free to provide any other possible solution if possible .

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create a method in native android and pass the value to react native. Check the below article
https://www.reactnative.guide/16-custom-native-modules/16.1-android-native-module.html
or
https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.